# Why does Backup and Sync occasionally create duplicate files with a (1) at the end of the file name?

Tags: windows, sync, google-backup-and-sync

Occasionally, Google Drive's Backup and Sync duplicates a file in my Windows Explorer, and adds  `(1)` at the end of the file name. **Why** does this happen?
I think it happens when files are moved.

In these cases, in my online Google Drive web app, only **one** instance of the file exists. And deleting the duplicate file in Windows Explorer deletes the other file as well. The problem can be solved by restoring the file after deleting it.

Last year, Renaud [asked this question on the Google Drive support forum](https://support.google.com/drive/forum/AAAAOxCWsTow-ocPgTpvOw), but instead of answering the question, the answerer described how to fix the problem (with long-winded methods that take much longer than simply deleting and then restoring the files).

Bonus points: Does this bug only occur with Backup and Sync, and not with InSync?